# Any solution how to get Family shared games to me on Steam via API?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I found this one API Method

```
GET api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&skip_unvetted_apps=false&steamid=76561198056238570&format=json
```

i found even undocumented param skip_unvetted_apps=false

But i cant figuring out how to get Family Shared game list of ID's

Any ideas?

Regards